# Rubymine - code folding ALL rspec examples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubymine, folding

Does anyone know if it's possible to code fold all rspec examples either automatically on opening a spec file or preferably by key binding from within Rubymine.

For a spec with lots of examples it would be very handy to just collapse all examples to get an overview of the complete spec for a model, controller, etc. This would make it far easier to review and check for any missing edge conditions for example.

What I would like is for the it block to code fold so that they result in something like...

```
it 'should test something' do ... end
```

... without having to manually code fold every individual example.

Comment: What text editor are you using? If using Rubymine, this functionality is built into the editor.

Comment: Thank you for the response however, although the functionality exists it only folds methods or custom blocks. I just cannot seem to get the custom blocks to work in the way I want

Answer (score 0):

Try going under Code > Folding > Expand All to Level > 3⌥⌘* in the menus. That should fold/expand to what you want.

[Code folding menu in RubyMine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXKaP.png)

More here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2016.2/code-folding.html#folding_menu

Comment: Sadly that won't work as typically `it do blocks` can be at any level, due to the nature of nesting `context` blocks.

Comment: i have a feeling that what I'm asking for is simply not possible :/